# Pagination in SeedStack Repositories

Tags: java, jpa, pagination, out-of-memory, seedstack

In my Java project, using SeedStack, I have queries to retrive data from an aggregate using specifications like this:

**UPDATE: Code example fixed to show the correct return type method**

```
public interface ProductRepository extends Repository<Product, ProductId> {
    default Stream<Product> discontinuedProducts() {
        return get(getSpecificationBuilder().of(Product.class)
                .property("discontinued").equalTo(true)
                .build()
        );
    }
}
```

In order to avoid potential out-of-memory errors, I want to use pagination to split data retrieved in some repository queries.

Moreover, I would like to use something very similar to pagination feature existing in String Data Repositories. I would like to keep some elements of the result (and not all of them) and process them by "page" without keeping all the data result in a Collection.

**Paging and Sorting in Spring:** https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html

However, I read SeedStack documentation and I did not find this feature.

**Repositories in SeedStack:** http://seedstack.org/docs/business/repositories/

So, I want to know what is the best way to paginate query results using SeedStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SeedStack provides helpers to do pagination in several differents ways but sadly the documentation is lacking on this front.

Before we go into details please note that you `discontinuedProducts()` method should return a `Stream<Product>` and not a `List<Product>` because the `get` method of the repository returns a stream.

The main way to do pagination with SeedStack is to use the [Paginator DSL](http://seedstack.org/javadoc/org/seedstack/business/pagination/dsl/Paginator.html) which plugs on top of a repository to provide the pagination.

Example 1 (paginating the stream directly):

```java
public class SomeResource {
    @Inject
    private Paginator paginator;
    @Inject
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Inject
    private FluentAssembler fluentAssembler;

    public void someMethod() {
        Page<Product> page = paginator.paginate(productRepository.discontinuedProducts())
                .byPage(1)
                .ofSize(10)
                .all();
    }
}
```

Example 2 (paginating the repository with a spec):

```java
public class SomeResource {
    @Inject
    private Paginator paginator;
    @Inject
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Inject
    private SpecificationBuilder specificationBuilder;

    public void someMethod() {
        Page<Product> page = paginator.paginate(productRepository)
                .byPage(1)
                .ofSize(10)
                .matching(specificationBuilder.of(Product.class)
                    .property("discontinued").equalTo(true)
                    .build());
    }
}
```

Example 3 (adding the DTO mapping in the mix):

```java
public class SomeResource {
    @Inject
    private Paginator paginator;
    @Inject
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Inject
    private SpecificationBuilder specificationBuilder;
    @Inject
    private FluentAssembler fluentAssembler;

    public void someMethod() {
        Page<ProductDto> page = fluentAssembler.assemble(
                paginator.paginate(productRepository)
                    .byPage(1)
                    .ofSize(10)
                    .matching(specificationBuilder.of(Product.class)
                        .property("discontinued").equalTo(true)
                        .build()))
                .toPageOf(ProductDto.class)
    }
}
```

In this last example, SeedStack will:

- Add a pagination predicate to your custom specification,
- Convert the resulting specification into the proper persistence query,
- Fetch the data and put it in a page,
- Convert the page of domain aggregate to a page of DTO using the correct assembler.

> Note that if you are going to reuse the same specification over and over, it may be useful to turn it into a class (like `DiscontinuedProductSpec`) or create a method in your repository to build it (like `buildDiscontinuedProductSpec()`).

**There are several other ways to combine these tools, please check the Javadoc of the [Paginator](http://seedstack.org/javadoc/org/seedstack/business/pagination/dsl/Paginator.html), [FluentAssembler](http://seedstack.org/javadoc/org/seedstack/business/assembler/dsl/FluentAssembler.html) and [Repository](http://seedstack.org/javadoc/org/seedstack/business/domain/Repository.html). You can also have a look at the [pagination integration test](https://github.com/seedstack/business/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/seedstack/business/PaginationIT.java) for more examples.**

Comment: Indeed, the `discontinuedProducts()` returns a `Stream<Product>` and not a `List<Product>`. Then, I am going to fix it. However, I took this example from SeedStack Repositories documentation to explain my problem without post code of my application. So, I think that maybe the documentation should be fixed also. Otherwise, this answer is reallly useful and I am going to check the **Javadoc** to decide how I am going to paginate in my application.

Comment: I just fixed the documentation to show `Stream` instead of `List`return values. Thanks for spotting the mistake !